# Angular 8 - Error - Cannot find module '@angular/forms/src/directives/validators

Tags: angular

I installed a new package:
`npm install --save ngx-cpf-cnpj`

And now I receive an error message.

My package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
"@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
"ngx-cpf-cnpj": "^1.0.3",
"ngx-mask": "^7.9.9",
"rxjs": "~6.4.0",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"
},
```

The error message:

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-cpf-cnpj/lib/cpf-cnpj-validator.directive.d.ts(6,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/forms/src/directives/validators'.
```

How can I solve this issue?

I don't have a folder `node_modules/@angular/forms/src`

[image]

This is my app.module.ts, I'm using FormsModule:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';    
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MaterialModule} from './material.module';
import {FlexLayoutModule} from '@angular/flex-layout';
...
import {NgxMaskModule} from 'ngx-mask';
import { NgxCpfCnpjModule } from  'ngx-cpf-cnpj';
...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgxMaskModule.forRoot(),
    NgxCpfCnpjModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    FormsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
```

Inside cpf-cnpj-validator.directive.d.ts there is this line:

```
import("@angular/forms/src/directives/validators").ValidationErrors;
```

Comment: Looks like you are importing from the wrong folder.

Comment: @Reactgular, wrong folder? I don't have a folder `@angular/forms/src/directives/validators` inside my node_modules

Comment: @danilo I think this library is not compatible with the latest version of Angular you have which is 8, that library was last updated 5 months ago.

Comment: Do you have `FormsModule` in your app module's list of imports?

Comment: @Reactgular, yes

Comment: @NadhirFalta Angular 7.x libraries are **supposed** to work with 8. I say supposed because I doubt it. lol

Comment: Did you enable the Ivy render feature?

Comment: @Reactgular, no

Comment: That import in the `.d.ts` file is really bad. Is this from the npm package?

Comment: @Reactgular, Inside cpf-cnpj-validator.directive.d.ts there is this line: import("@angular/forms/src/directives/validators").ValidationErrors;

Comment: @Reactgular, yes, I used npm install --save ngx-cpf-cnpj to install

Comment: You should stop using this package. It does not have a linked github account, and I have to google to find it. It's doesn't look properly published. Go to the github repo and copy/paste the code you need and maintain it yourself. Open an issue on their repo to report the bug if you want, but I wouldn't add this as a dependency (maybe even a security risk). https://github.com/DiegoSestito/ngx-cpf-cnpj

Comment: @Reactgular, I'll stop using, thanks

Comment: I have a similar issue when upgrading to angular 8 as well, `Cannot find module '@angular/forms/src/directives/control_value_accessor'`, coming from `ngx-bootstrap` (node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/timepicker/models/index.d.ts) - Version ~3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

use

```
import {*****} from "@angular/forms";
```

instead of

```
import {*****} from "@angular/forms/src/directives/validators";
```